# One time validation of user input to run application

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I've made a WinForms application in C#.NET.

On first run I'm checking if 2 strings are equal, if its TRUE then the main form appears. However currently, this check is done whenever I start the program.

How can I pass this "validation result" to the computer so that every next run of the application, there will be no more checks needed?

Comment: Save it somewhere, in a file in example

Comment: Dear Cid, may I kindly ask for some example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to store validation data in the registry. If the lines are equal, then create a branch in the registry and write the necessary data into it. Next, at the next start, we check for the presence of a branch and data in it. I attach a quick example.

```
        string FisrtString = "Temp";
        string SecondString = "Temp";
        string SubBaseKeyString = @"SOFTWARE\ApplicationName";
        RegistryKey vmsBaseKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(SubBaseKeyString, true);
        if (vmsBaseKey != null)
        {
            var Value = vmsBaseKey.GetValue("Validate");
            if (Value != null)
            {
                if (Value.ToString() == "1")
                {
                    //The user check passed here, you can open the window
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Here you must specify the action if the key is missing. Additional string comparison possible
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (FisrtString == SecondString)
            {
                //If the first line is equal to the second line, then assign a value
                //The user check passed here, you can open the window
                RegistryKey KEY_CREATE = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(SubBaseKeyString);
                KEY_CREATE.SetValue("Validate", "1");
                KEY_CREATE.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //If the first line is not equal to the second line, then we perform the desired action
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank You very much Maxim_A I will work around with Your example, this will work only if user have proper privileges right ?

Comment: @Kuba Do if the key or other information that is necessary for verification is on the computer in any form, then this is not safe. even if you use some kind of encryption algorithm, you can decompile your code and see what kind of algorithm is used. in order for data validation to take place more safely, a solution using a server is needed. but that’s another topic for discussion.

Comment: @Kuba Do each user on the local computer has its own separate branch in the registry. in its branch "HKEY_CURRENT_USER". in it, the user can do absolutely any action. There is a branch HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and here in it the user can only perform actions if he has the corresponding administrator rights

Answer (score 0):

You could save the result of your check into a config file and read it next time your program starts from the config file

Comment: what if User before that check will change the file ?

Comment: Instead of using "a file", use the Isolated storage (google: "How to: Read and Write to Files in Isolated Storage"). Or write the info to the alternate data stream, maybe of your Excecutable (or if you have already a config file already present ...). The alternate data stream cannot be changed easy by an average skilled user.